# Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented when trying to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working with NBA data and I want to get the info for tallest and shortest player for a certain team in each season and then plot it to see trends changing during years.

This is how my code looks like:

```
nba8 = nba[nba['team_abbreviation'] == "PHI"]

nba8 = nba8.groupby(['season', 'team_abbreviation']).agg({'player_height': ['min', 'max']})

nba8 = nba8.reset_index()

x_ticks = nba8.index[::4]

nba8.plot(x='season', y=['player_height', 'player_height'], kind='line')

plt.xticks(x_ticks, nba8['season'][::4])

plt.xlabel('Season')
plt.ylabel('Height (cm)')
plt.title('Tallest and Shortest Player in Team "PHI" in Each Season')

plt.show()
```

But when I do it, I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented
```

Any idea on how can I solve it?